# Characterization of convex hull in terms of (in)equality properties

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-hulls

Let $A \subseteq \{0,1\}^n$ be a set of vectors that satisfy some (in)equality properties, e.g.,

$$ \begin{aligned} A &= \left\{ x \in \{0,1\}^n : x_1 = x_2 \right\} \\ A &= \left\{ x \in \{0,1\}^n : x_1 < x_2, x_3 + x_4 = 1 \right\} \end{aligned} $$

More abstractly, in logical language,

$$ A = \left\{ x \in \{0,1\}^n : \varphi_1(x),\dots, \varphi_m(x) \right\} $$

where $\varphi_i$ is a property of the $x_i$'s only involving "$=$", "$+$", "$<$" and numerical constants. Sorry that I can't be more precise.

I am curious if it's true that the convex hull of $A$ (assuming $A$ non-empty in light of the counter-example that @daw gave below) contains all and only vectors in $[0,1]^n$ that satisfy the same properties. The convex hull of $A$ would be a subset of these vectors, because these properties are preserved under linear combination. So the hard part is to prove the converse. This seems to be true in simple cases, e.g. when $A=\{x\in\{0,1\}^n: x_1=x_2\}$, then $\mathrm{conv}(A)=\{x\in [0,1]^n: x_1=x_2\}$. Any thought/reference pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the Krein-Milman theorem of any relevance to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. Take
$$ 
A =\{ x \in \{0,1\} :\  2x_1=1\},
$$
then $A= \emptyset$ and $\{ x \in [0,1] :\  2x_1=1\}=\{1/2\}$.

Comment: Ah good point! I should've added that $A\neq\emptyset$, though perhaps there are similar counter-examples....thx!